# UIScrollView doesn't scroll in the bottom part of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a UIScrollView with 1 image and 2 tableview inside. The scroll works correctly if I tap on the center and on the top of the screen but doesn't works if I try to scroll tapping on the bottom of the screen. Here the code that I used.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:self.scrollView];

self.theImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, lenghtImage, hightImage)];
self.theImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.theImage];

self.tableA = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosA, self.bounds.size.width, heightA];
self.tableA.delegate = self;
self.tableA.dataSource = self;
self.tableA.scrollEnabled = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableA];

self.tableB = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosB, self.bounds.size.width, hightB)];
self.tableB.delegate = self;
self.tableB.dataSource = self;
self.tableB.scrollEnabled = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableB];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,heightImage+heightTableA+heightTableB);
```

Comment: Scrollview height must be greater then your view

Comment: How much? I tried to increase the scrollview height but anything change

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view `contentSize` should be equal or greater than its total subview size.

You calculate `contentSize` height by adding all of its subview height and also their y coordinate.

so it should be:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, hightImage + yPosA + heightA + yPosB + hightB);
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is not the contentSize. I've tried your solution and I have tried to change many times the contentSize, but the problem is always the same: if I try to scroll tapping on the bottom of the screen the scroll doesn't works. It is like there is a part of the screen that not reacts to touch events.